# Although I have fulltext index in mysql table, however ERROR 1191 occurs when I execute my search algorithm

Tags: mysql, algorithm

When I execute my search algorithm, I get this error: ERROR 1191 Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list, although I have created FULLTEXT index in the table with the same columns and order.

Show create table:

```
FULLTEXT KEY `company_name`(`company_name`,`job_title`,`career_field`,`responsibility`)
```

Search Algorithm:

```
SELECT * ,Match(company_name) AGAINST ('$keyword') as company_rel, Match(job_title) AGAINST ('$keyword') as title_rel, Match(career_field) AGAINST ('$keyword') as career_rel, Match(responsibility) AGAINST ('$keyword') as responsibility_rel FROM job_post WHERE Match (company_name,job_title,career_field,responsibility) AGAINST ('$keyword') AND (career_field LIKE '%%') ORDER BY title_rel * 1.3 + responsibility_rel * 1.2 + career_rel * 1.1 + company_rel * 1 DESC Limit 0 , 20
```

I searched hours and hours, tried everything and couldn't find a solution, please help.

Comment: If you are trying to match just `company_name`, you need to have a fulltext index for JUST `company_name`. You cannot get a relative weight that way.

Comment: I have added another index for each column and used the same search algorithm, it worked fine, if there's any other comments against the syntax that I'm using, I'd really appreciate if you could tell me.  Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, one comment would be that all your matches will cost some performance (so check if you really need it). Als your relatives weights will probably not work exactly as you think they do (as the value is relative to the other rows of the column, not the other columns). If e.g. nearly every `job_title` (every row) contains the word `mysql` (resulting in a very low match-value (which for MyISAM-tables actually is 0)), and just one `company` contains the word `mysql` (=high match-value), the company will still be listed first even if you weight the title with 1.3.

Comment: @Solarflare yes, I've been doing some tests and I realized the same results you are describing, therefore I've changed the weighting to the following, do you think this would be better, because I believe I need this weighting to be done some way. 'code' ORDER BY title_rel * 6 + responsibility_rel * 3 + career_rel * 1.5 + company_rel * 1

Comment: It will basically have the same effect (0*6 is still 0). You could try e.g. something like `order by (title_rel like '%$keyword%') * 6 + ...`. Instead of `like`, you can write a custom function that makes sure you only look for complete words (as `like '%$keyword%'` will also find partial words), although accepting partial matches might be fine (or even better) for the weight.

Comment: @Solarflare Many thanks for the help, I'd appreciate if you advise some sort of link, document or website that I can refer to during future work with the something similar to such cases.

Comment: No problem, that is what we are here for. And some links: [www.stackoverflow.com](https://www.stackoverflow.com) and the [MySQL Fulltext search manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html)